# Show random images

Tags: java, android, random, bitmap, drawable

Part of the code of the app I'm developing must show a card randomly between 100 diferent cards. This is, when I touch a button, between 100 images I have, it must choose one and show.

But I'm have some kind of issue, I think realted to the size. This is my code:

```
private final int rollAnimations = 50;
private final int delayTime = 15;
private final int[] cardFaces = new int[] {R.drawable.c1, R.drawable.c2, R.drawable.c3, R.drawable.c4, R.drawable.c5,
        R.drawable.c6, R.drawable.c7, R.drawable.c8, R.drawable.c9, R.drawable.c10,
        R.drawable.c10, R.drawable.c12, R.drawable.c13, R.drawable.c14, R.drawable.c5,
        R.drawable.c16, R.drawable.c17, R.drawable.c18, R.drawable.c19, R.drawable.c20,
        R.drawable.c21, R.drawable.c22, R.drawable.c23, R.drawable.c24, R.drawable.c25,
        R.drawable.c26, R.drawable.c27, R.drawable.c28, R.drawable.c29, R.drawable.c30,
        R.drawable.c31, R.drawable.c32, R.drawable.c33, R.drawable.c34, R.drawable.c35,
        R.drawable.c36, R.drawable.c37, R.drawable.c38, R.drawable.c39, R.drawable.c40,
        R.drawable.c41, R.drawable.c42, R.drawable.c43, R.drawable.c44, R.drawable.c45,
        R.drawable.c46, R.drawable.c47, R.drawable.c48, R.drawable.c49, R.drawable.c50,
        R.drawable.c51, R.drawable.c52, R.drawable.c53, R.drawable.c54, R.drawable.c55,
        R.drawable.c56, R.drawable.c57, R.drawable.c58, R.drawable.c59, R.drawable.c60,
        R.drawable.c61, R.drawable.c62, R.drawable.c63, R.drawable.c64, R.drawable.c65,
        R.drawable.c66, R.drawable.c67, R.drawable.c68, R.drawable.c69, R.drawable.c70,
        R.drawable.c71, R.drawable.c72, R.drawable.c73, R.drawable.c74, R.drawable.c75,
        R.drawable.c76, R.drawable.c77, R.drawable.c78, R.drawable.c79, R.drawable.c80,
        R.drawable.c81, R.drawable.c82, R.drawable.c83, R.drawable.c84, R.drawable.c85,
        R.drawable.c86, R.drawable.c87, R.drawable.c88, R.drawable.c89, R.drawable.c90,
        R.drawable.c91, R.drawable.c92, R.drawable.c93, R.drawable.c94, R.drawable.c95,
        R.drawable.c96, R.drawable.c97, R.drawable.c98, R.drawable.c99, R.drawable.c100,};
private final Drawable mCard[] = new Drawable[100];
private final Random randomGen = new Random();
private final int roll[] = new int[] {100};
private ImageView card;
private LinearLayout cardContainer;
private Handler animationHandler;
private boolean paused = false;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.card_game);


    /*Here I define each image resurce to a position of the array*/
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        mCard[i] = getResources().getDrawable(cardFaces[i]);
    }

    /*Instead of touching a button, I've modfied to touch the screen*/
    cardContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cardContainer);
    cardContainer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                rollCards();
            } catch (Exception e) {};
        }
    });

    animationHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            card.setImageDrawable(mCard[roll[0]]);
        }
    };
}



/******************
 * 
 * METHODS
 * 
 ******************/

/**Thread that rolls the cards like if it would be a dice*/
private void rollCards() {
    if (paused) return;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < rollAnimations; i++) {
                doRoll();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.roll);
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
}


/***/
private void doRoll() {
    roll[0] = randomGen.nextInt(100);

    synchronized (getLayoutInflater()) {
        animationHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
    try { // delay to alloy for smooth animation
        Thread.sleep(delayTime);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what shows the logcat:

```
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=49187KB, Allocated=48011KB)
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreateScaledBitmap(Native Method)
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:744)
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:766)
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:492)
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2053)
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:683)
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778):    at com.example.beding.CardActivity.onCreate(CardActivity.java:68)
05-23 15:50:31.458: E/AndroidRuntime(21778):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
```

Line 68 of cardActivity refers to this: `mCard[i] = getResources().getDrawable(cardFaces[i]);`

Comment: How big are these images?

Comment: By the way, there's an extra comma here: `R.drawable.c96, R.drawable.c97, R.drawable.c98, R.drawable.c99, R.drawable.c100,}`. And I think this `R.drawable.c10, R.drawable.c12, R.drawable.c13, R.drawable.c14, R.drawable.c5,` should end in **.c15**, not **.c5**.

Comment: With the OutOfMemory, you'll need to alter how you're loading the images. Perhaps, do a reference to the file, and only load it into memory when it's supposed to show?

Comment: @Aleks G the images are 20k more or less

Comment: @Der Golem yeeph, deleted!

Comment: @Patrick J Abare II What do you porpouse? any suggestion?

Comment: @masmic_87: also change c5 to c15, in the same array definition, near c14 (see my edited comment)

Comment: @Der Golem thaks, this happens when trying to do all fast :)

Comment: Do a reference array to the files, like, a String or an Enum. Use your random selection from that array to load 5 random images into memory in a queue. When you read, the "random" one from the first step in the queue, load another into the back of the queue. That should reduce any visible load times.

Comment: @Patrick J Abare II If you write that in an answer with a little example using my code, it could be usefull for anyone that needs something like this, an also I'll accept it

Comment: I will pseudo-code it, but sure.

Comment: Posted, hope the logic makes sense. I didn't test it, just kind of an outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified a bit my code but finally I got another way to achieve this. Basically I have changed the way the cards are shown. Before they were shown as a dice roll, this is, there was a fast preview of some of them an then it stoped in a random one. Now I just show the back side of the card and then the card is shown, more likely a card game.

For anyone that sees this useful, this is how I have done it:

**card_list_array.xml** -> Here we define al existing cards

```
<resources>  
    <array name="cardFaces">       
        <item>@drawable/c1</item>
        <item>@drawable/c2</item>
        //...
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.card_game);

    card = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card);

    card.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            card.setImageResource(R.drawable.backside);
            card.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int rdmCard = randomCard();
                    card.setImageResource(rdmCard);
                }
            },100);

        }
    });
}

public int randomCard() {
    TypedArray cardsArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.cardFaces);
    int randomNumber =  (int)(Math.random() * ((100 - 0) + 1));
    int card = cardsArray.getResourceId(randomNumber, randomNumber);
    cardsArray.recycle();
    return card;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the above comments, this is how I would handle the OutOfMemory Issue.

```
//Populate Reference Array
ImageEnum[] refArr = {ImageEnum.C1,ImageEnum.2......};

Constructor()
{
    //For loop to loadRandom() 5 different values from refArr
    //Load each Drawable and place in a Queue Object
    queue.add(loadRandom());
}

Drawable loadRandom()
{
    ImageEnum rnd = refArr[Random.nextInt() % ImageEnum.length];

    return rnd.loadDrawable();
}

Drawable getRandomDrawable()
{
    queue.add(loadRandom()); //Ensure there is always a new one to replace the retrieved
    return queue.getFirst()//Not sure if that's the method
}
```